# Minimum number of allowed transpositions to convert a permutation into another

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, permutations

I'm working on a problem regarding quantum circuit compilation.

Consider two permutations of integers from 1 to N. I want to estimate the minimum number of swaps needed to convert one to another. The issue is that swaps are not allowed between all the positions but between specific positions.

Each position can be considered a node of a connected graph whose edges connects swappable positions.

I know about Cayley distance for the case in which all the swaps are allowed and Kendall-Tau distance for when only adjacent elements of a permutation string can be swapped.

I suspect that concepts related to cycle decomposition and permutation groups might be applicable to this problem, but I'm struggling to find a way to incorporate these ideas effectively.

I've tested a Breadth-First Search algorithm exploring all the permutations considering allowed swaps until the target is found. I'm curious if there's a more efficient or smarter strategy for larger N.

Any suggestions or guidance on optimizing the algorithm or leveraging permutation group concepts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Using graphs, I'd doubt there is something faster than BFS.